# (quasi)coherent rings for which $\dim R[T]\neq \dim R+1$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra, coherent-rings

What are some some examples of (quasi)coherent rings for which $\dim R[T]\neq \dim R+1$?

Why (hopefully geometrically) should we not always have equality?

**Notation.** Let $I,J$ be two ideals of commutative ring. If $I=aR,J=bR$, denote the conductor of $J$ into $I$ by $(I:J)$ by $(a:b)$.

**Definition.** A commutative ring is quasicoherent if for any finite subset $ \left\{ a_1,\dots ,a_n,c \right\} \subset R$ the ideals $a_1R\cap \cdots \cap a_nR$ and $(0:c)$ are finitely generated.

Comment: What is a quasicoherent ring?

Comment: I have a found a definition of quasi coherent rings here: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-10/S0002-9939-00-05882-2/S0002-9939-00-05882-2.pdf